# Exclude Rows where contains anything but a number

Tags: sql, sql-server

**Objective:**

Is there a simple way of excluding any result that contains anything but a number

These, for example, should be excluded:

- 123595104-
- 3229359Ab102
- 1204-12034-023425

Comment: Make it a numeric field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
where col not like '%[^0-9]%'
```

or

```
where patindex('%[^0-9]%', col) = 0
```

`patindex()` would be most useful if you need to find the position of matches and parse the string.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend `NOT LIKE`:

```
where col NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%'
```